# how to choose which row to insert with same id in sql?

Tags: sql, ssis

so Basically I have a table called "table_1" :

```
ID   Index          STATUS          TIME        DESCRIPTION
1     15          pending           1:00       Started Pending
1     16          pending           1:05       still in request
1     17          pending           1:10       still in request
1     18          complete          1:20       Transaction has been completed
2     19          pending           2:25       request has been started
2     20          pending           2:30       in progress
2     21          pending           2:35       in progess still
2     22          pending           2:40       still pending
2     23          complete          2:45       Transaction Compeleted
```

I need to insert these data into my second table "table_2" where only start and compelete times are included, so my "table_2" should like this:

```
ID   Index   STATUS          TIME          DESCRIPTION
1     15     pending         1:00          Started Pending
1     18     complete        1:20          Transaction has been completed
2     19     pending         2:25          request has been started
2     23     complete        2:45          Transaction Compeleted
```

if anyone can help me write sql query for this I would highly appreciate it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have multiple "ID"s the same, they're not an ID. Perhaps you should reconsider your design.

Comment: would you consider ID like specific identifier

Comment: The specific identifier in this case is the entire row. The primary key is all three fields

Comment: I'm freestyling here, but I'd imagine the ID is some kind of job. So you'd have a JOB table with a PK, then you'd have some kind of JOB_STATUS_HISTORY table, with an FK to JOB and either a naturally unique key or a surrogate ID which would be unique. I'd probably also abstract out your status somehow as the repeating strings could be brittle for future use. Perhaps consider actually having a "start" state, so it goes start, pending, complete etc. Although in this case, pending seems to only denote that the job is still alive so a different design altogether would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO t2 (ID, STATUS, TIME)
SELECT ID, STATUS, MIN(TIME) FROM t1 t1top
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ID=t1top.ID AND STATUS='Complete')
GROUP BY ID, STATUS
ORDER BY CAST(ID AS UNSIGNED) ASC, STATUS DESC
```

After the insert is made, if you want to see the result according to your example, you have to run the following select:

```
SELECT ID, STATUS, TIME FROM table_1
ORDER BY CAST(ID AS UNSIGNED) ASC, STATUS DESC
```

thats EXACTLY RIGHT, however I dont want to just SEE it that way, it needs to be inserted in the second table in that manner as well, any idea?

Comment: what is t1top? sorry I am a newbie

Comment: that's an alias for your main table t1, so the engine doesn't mix itself up between the "t1top" which is the top one, and the t1 from the EXISTS clause

But just name it whatever is your preference

Comment: I get a syntax error,Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 45
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
I truly appreciate your help

Comment: here you go, I'm sorry for the tipo

Comment: no problem! If you think it solved your problem enough I won't mind the "accepted" status ;) just to reach my daily 200 ;)

Comment: The second half of this statement will select all records from t1 where status='Complete'.  It seems to me that it needs to have another clause ensuring that only the matching Complete with the same ID is unioned.

Comment: yes, the above query was inserting twice the complete status rows. Removing the union part corrects the issue.

Comment: Also, as discovered in the posters other question if the ID is a varchar it might need to be cast as an int to appear to sort correctly.  `cast(id as int)`

Comment: it outputs it wrong, what the code output is compelete, pending, complete, pending.it needs to be pending, complete, pernding, compelte

Comment: anyone know how I can sorted by time?

Comment: by time only? Or by id and time?

Comment: it needs to be inserted in that order, THANK YOU I really appreciate your help

Comment: the insert doesn't matter, the select does. please explain your point.

Comment: It needs to be inserted to the second table in exact same way as example where at the end its sorted by id and time

Comment: Also, CAST(ID AS UNSIGNED).  Is that a MySql thing - not familiar with that?

Comment: I updated a few minutes ago already the insert to order it as well but I don't know if it will work...

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table_2
SELECT id,status,min(time)
FROM table_1 AS t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM table_1
             WHERE id=t1.id
                 AND status='complete')
GROUP BY id,status
```

I think that should do it for you, haven't tested it though :(

Comment: Yep I'm just adding the check to make sure a Complete exists - any more info on how it didn't work?

Comment: hi there? it partially worked however it didnt sort them correctly, the result                                                       was 1 complete 2012-05-31 01:20:00.000
2 complete 2012-05-31 02:45:00.000
1 pending 2012-05-31 01:00:00.000
2 pending 2012-05-31 02:25:00.000

Comment: Oh sorting - my bad, completely forgot. It's there now (that new bottom line). If the pending and completes are backwards then add the keyword DESC after status in the orderby. My brain is being silly and I can't figure out whether it is or isn't meant to be there...

Comment: Wait silly me, you can't sort an insert. You need to apply the ORDER BY id,status when you're SELECTing from that table - like SELECT * FROM table_2 ORDER BY id,status

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you, one last favor, the id is now not sorted it goes 1,2 compelete,compelte ,1,2 pending, pending

Comment: That shouldn't be happening - you sure you didn't put ORDER BY status,id instead of ORDER BY id,status? You want ID to be sorted first

Answer (score 0):

you could get 
all the start times like this:

```
   select id, status, min(time) 
   from table_1 
   where status = 'Pending'
   group by id, status
```

then completion like this:

```
   select id, status, time
   from table_1 
   where status = 'Complete'
   group by id, status
```

you can use union to use both, and of course try:

```
   insert into table_2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (ID, STATUS, TIME, DESCRIPTION)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.STATUS, t1.TIME, t1.DESCRIPTION FROM table_1 as t1 
WHERE STATUS = 'complete' 
OR TIME = (SELECT min(TIME) FROM table_1 WHERE ID = t1.ID) 
ORDER BY ID asc, STATUS desc
```