# how to do select distinct select in sql?

Tags: sql, ssis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to choose which row to insert with same id in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842634/how-to-choose-which-row-to-insert-with-same-id-in-sql)

I have a table called "table_1" :

```
ID   Index          STATUS          TIME        DESCRIPTION
1     15          pending           1:00       Started Pending
1     16          pending           1:05       still in request
1     17          pending           1:10       still in request
1     18          complete          1:20       Transaction has been completed
2     19          pending           2:25       request has been started
2     20          pending           2:30       in progress
2     21          pending           2:35       in progess still
2     22          pending           2:40       still pending
2     23          complete          2:45       Transaction Compeleted
```

I need to insert these data into my second table "table_2" where only start and complete times are included, so my "table_2" should be like this:

```
ID   Index   STATUS          TIME          DESCRIPTION
1     15     pending         1:00          Started Pending
1     18     complete        1:20          Transaction has been completed
2     19     pending         2:25          request has been started
2     23     complete        2:45          Transaction Completed
```

Here is some code I already have, I have problem getting the right associated description because it does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (ID, STATUS, TIME)
SELECT ID, STATUS, MIN(TIME) FROM myTable1 t1top
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myTable1 WHERE ID=t1top.ID AND STATUS='Complete')
GROUP BY ID, STATUS
ORDER BY ID  ASC, STATUS DESC
```

If anyone can help me write sql query for this I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: yes my friend thats the same question I asked yesterday, with no result yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (ID, STATUS, TIME, DESCRIPTION)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.STATUS, t1.TIME, t1.DESCRIPTION FROM table_1 as t1 
WHERE STATUS = 'complete' 
OR TIME = (SELECT min(TIME) FROM table_1 WHERE ID = t1.ID) 
ORDER BY ID asc, STATUS desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can self-join the table and select from that, assuming the timestamps are unique.  (If they are not, the description is not uniquely defined by your data).

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (ID, STATUS, TIME, DESCRIPTION)
SELECT t1top.ID, t1top.STATUS, MIN(t1top.TIME), t1Copy.DESCRIPTION
FROM myTable1 t1top
    JOIN myTable1 t1Copy ON t1top.ID = t1Copy.ID
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myTable1 WHERE ID=t1top.ID AND STATUS='Complete')
    AND MIN(t1top.TIME) = t1Copy.TIME
GROUP BY ID, STATUS
ORDER BY ID ASC, STATUS DESC
```

Comment: Hey there,yes Time,ID and Index are all unique

Comment: I get this error An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: @user1429595 - Oops.  Hopefully fixed.  Please retag (edit) your question, add a tag for your version of SQL Server (2005 or 2008, probably).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable1 WHERE DESCRIPTION = '%started%' OR DESCRIPTION = '%complete%' ORDER BY ID, STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partition function for this:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Index, a.STATUS, a.TIME, a.DESCRIPTION FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Index, STATUS, TIME, DESCRIPTION, 
    MIN(Index) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS first_index,
    MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'complete' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS is_complete
   FROM myTable1
) a
WHERE a.is_complete = 1 AND (a.status = 'complete' OR a.index = a.first_index)
```

In other words, select the first and last rows of events that have been completed.

Comment: Thank you, it partially worked, THanks again

Comment: @user1429595 a little SQL humor there?  That was partially funny ;)